# Before pseudo element not working in Internet Explorer for <a> element

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer

I'm using one juicer.io plugin for Social Media.

There is Load More button in `<a>` element.
I would like to change text from Load More to Mehr Laben, I did that using `::before` element and works fine for all browsers except IE 11.

I've created example on JSFiddle to demonstrate problem.

Problem is IE 11 can't read pseudo element, maybe only for .

I've tried to replace `::before` with `:before` but not working.

**Note:** This `<a>` was generated dynamically, and I can't wrap.

JSFIDDLE: https://jsfiddle.net/uy4xewpr/
You can run this inside IE and you will see empty page, but inside Chrome ... works fine.

HTML:

```
<a href="#">READ MORE</a>
```

CSS:

```
a{
    visibility: hidden;
    color: #000;
    font-size: 17px;
    display: flex;
    text-transform: none;
}
a::before{
    display: inline-block;
    visibility: visible;
    content: "Mehr Laden";
    padding-left: 32px;
    padding-top: 3px;
    min-width: 124px;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

<strike>I don't really think the behavior of IE11 is odd. In fact this should be expected.. pseudo elements are children to the parent element so setting the `a` to have visibility `hidden` then setting the visibility of the pseudo content to be `visible` shouldn't work.</strike> This is actually wrong, I thought visibility should behave like `opacity` where you cannot unset the opacity in a child of a parent with different opacity. It's probably a bug in IE11 not bad implementation from other browsers like I thought.

To fix this remove the visibility and use `font-size: 0` on the `a` then set the `font-size` to the desired value on the pseudo element

```
a {
    color: #000;
    font-size: 0;
    display: flex;
    text-transform: none;
}
a::before {
    display: inline-block;
    font-size: 17px;
    content: "Mehr Laden";
    padding-left: 32px;
    padding-top: 3px;
    min-width: 124px;
}
```

The only drawback is that it won't work on Android 2 which is a very old version you probably don't care about

Comment: Actually, the `visibility` property does enable you to set a parent element with `hidden` and a child element with `visible` - so I do think that this behavior is odd https://codepen.io/danield770/pen/WEBrvj

Comment: @Danield I just found out about that. I never really knew it I thought it behave like `opacity`.

Answer (score 3):

You can use two tricks here:

- `font-size: 0`

```css
a {
  font-size: 0;
  color: #000;
  font-size: 0;
  display: flex;
  text-transform: none;
}

a::before {
  font-size: 17px;
  display: inline-block;
  content: "Mehr Laden";
  padding-left: 32px;
  padding-top: 3px;
  min-width: 124px;
}
```

```html
<a href="#">READ MORE</a>
```

- `color: transparent`

```css
a {
  font-size: 17px;
  color: transparent;
  display: flex;
  text-transform: none;
}

a::before {
  color: #000;
  display: inline-block;
  content: "Mehr Laden";
  padding-left: 32px;
  padding-top: 3px;
  min-width: 124px;
}
```

```html
<a href="#">READ MORE</a>
```